# How to remove "integer" array from object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, integer

I got this input

```
    var input=[ "Axel",
                4,
                4.21,
                { name : 'Bob', age : 16 },
                { type : 'fish', model : 'golden fish' },
                [1,2,3],
                "John",
                { name : 'Peter', height: 1.90}          ];
```

and the Result must be this one

```
    [ { name : 'Bob', age : 16 },
      { type : 'fish', model : 'golden fish' },        
      { name : 'Peter', height: 1.90}            ];
```

Comment: And where did Axel and John go?

Comment: are you trying to remove all elements that are not an object?

Comment: yes, im trying to get only the objects

Comment: Look at the answer from Paul below, that should solve your issue.

Comment: toretto, there is a fiddle with Paul's answer below, in my comment, that might help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.filter`, only keep *Objects* which are not *Arrays*

```
var input = ["Axel",
    4,
    4.21,
    {name: 'Bob', age: 16},
    {type: 'fish', model: 'golden fish'},
    [1, 2, 3],
    "John",
    {name: 'Peter', height: 1.90}
];

input = input.filter(function (e) {
    return (typeof e === 'object') && !Array.isArray(e);
}); /*
[
    {"name": "Bob", "age": 16},
    {"type": "fish", "model": "golden fish"},
    {"name": "Peter", "height": 1.9}
]
*/
```

Comment: posted this 49secs after you :)  Just deleted mine and upvoted yours =D

Comment: doesnt work ... "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: What browser? May be `Array.isArray` is not implemented in your browser

Comment: I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/6807oz5L/) for this. Paul, you needed to set the input variable at the filter line so the variable is updated (I made the edit).  I ran this in chrome and ie9, it worked good.

Answer (score 0):

Try using array filter to remove the unwanted elements. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

To remove all integers

```
var filteredList = input.filter(function(val) {
    return isNaN(val);
}):
/*
filteredList is now =
{ name: 'Bob', age: 16 },
{ type: 'fish', model: 'golden fish' },
[ 1, 2, 3 ],
'John',
{ name: 'Peter', height: 1.9 } ]
*/
```